# Can't arrange TabLayout icons to the left

Tags: android, android-tablayout

In my project I have this code

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.location);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.list);
```

that makes the icons appear on top of the text, and I need them to the left

I tried this:

```
ConstraintLayout cl = (ConstraintLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
TextView tab = cl.findViewById(R.id.textViewTab);
tab.setText("Ver mapa");
tab.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabActive));
tab.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.location, 0, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tab);

tab.setText("Ver lista");
tab.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabInactive));
tab.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.list, 0, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tab);
```

But I get this result

[image: crappy tabs]

Pretty, but not what I'm looking for

Comment: why you are not doing this by xml

Comment: Would that make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to initialize  the second view:

```
ConstraintLayout cl = (ConstraintLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
TextView tab = cl.findViewById(R.id.textViewTab);
tab.setText("Ver mapa");
tab.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabActive));
tab.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.location, 0, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tab);

tab = cl.findViewById(R.id.textViewTab); // This was missing     tab.setText("Ver lista");
tab.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabInactive));
tab.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.list, 0, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tab);
```